# PHP mySQL FPDF html2pdf can't get img tag to print to pdf

Tags: php, html, image, fpdf, html2pdf

So I have a line of html code that will run when I use echo in a document without FPDF and html2pdf, but when I try to put it into a PDF with WriteHTML() nothing shows up.

Here is the code for FPDF where it doesn't work :

`$pdf->WriteHTML("<img src='data:image/png;base64," . $data . "' width = '" . $width . "' >");`

And here it is without FPDF where it works:

`echo ("<img src='data:image/png;base64," . $data . "' width = '" . $width . "' >");`

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working? Any answer or sol

Comment: Have you considered using DomPDF instead? (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Answer (score 0):

Yes HTML2PDF does not handle PNG well (as my experience it does not  supports PNG at all) so use JPG instead

Regards